# How to add pooled standard error in tbl_summary() and eta effect size?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to include Pooled Standard Error (PSE) and Eta square to `tbl_summary()`. PSE is calculated by `sqrt(mean(residuals^2)/n)`, I tried to calculate step by step by extracting the residuals from either `aov()` or `lm()`, but I got the error saying `The dimension of respected variable and the added statistic do not match. Expecting statistic/dataframe to be length/ no. rows 1`. Here is my code:

```
PSE <- function(data, variable, by,...) {
    aov(data[["variable"]] ~ as.factor(data[[by]]))$residuals
  }

Dataset_TPA_Full %>%
  select(diet,hardness_g,adhesiveness_g_sec, resilence, cohesion, springiness, gumminess, chewiness, firmness_g_force_1, density_g_l)%>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = diet,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sem}",
    label = list(hardness_g = "Hardness (g)", 
                 adhesiveness_g_sec = "Adhesiveness (g/ sec)", 
                 resilence = "Resilience", 
                 cohesion = "Cohesion", 
                 springiness = "Springiness", 
                 gumminess = "Gumminess", 
                 chewiness = "Chewiness", 
                 firmness_g_force_1 = "Firmness (g)", 
                 density_g_l = "Density (g/ L)")
    ) %>% 
    add_p(
      test = all_continuous() ~ "aov",
    ) %>%
  add_stat(fns = all_continuous() ~ PSE) %>% 
  modify_header(label = "**Treatment**", p.value = "**p-value**") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  bold_levels()
```

Also when I tried to add Eta squared using this code, it return missing data argument when I put it in the `add_stat()` function

```
my_ES_test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  aovmod = aov(data[[variable]] ~ data[[by]])
  lsr::etaSquared(aovmod)[1,1]
}
```

Can you help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: Please include all `library` lines for non-base methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

sem <- function(x){
  sqrt(var(x, na.rm=TRUE)/sum(!is.na(x)))
}

PSE <- function(data, variable, by,...) {
  e <- aov(data[[variable]] ~ as.factor(data[[by]]))$residuals
  sqrt(mean(e^2)/length(e))
}

mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, mpg, hp, disp, drat, qsec)%>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = cyl,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sem}",
    label = list(mpg = "Miles per Gallon", 
                 hp = "Horsepower", 
                 disp = "Displacement", 
                 drat = "Rear Axel Ratio", 
                 qsec = "1/4 Mile Time")
  ) %>% 
  add_p(
    test = all_continuous() ~ "aov",
  ) %>%
  add_stat(fns = all_continuous() ~ PSE) %>% 
  modify_header(label = "**Treatment**", p.value = "**p-value**", add_stat_1 = "**PSE**") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  bold_levels()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note, the `PSE()` function had two problems.  First, the `data[["variable"]]` should be `data[[variable]]` (without the quotes around `variable`).  Second, you had the function return the residuals, not the PSE calculation you described in the question.  Now, it returns the appropriate result.  I also am not sure where you got the `sem()` function, so I just made one that calculates the standard error of the mean.

---

#### Updated PSE function

```r
PSE <- function(data, variable, by,...) {
  s <- data %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(by)) %>% 
    summarise(s = var(!!sym(variable)), 
              n = n()) %>% 
    mutate(num = s*(n-1))
  psd <- sqrt(sum(s$num)/(sum(s$n) - nrow(s)))
  psd*sqrt(sum(1/s$n))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! For the `PSE()` function, I just tried to see if it can omit the residuals or not, then I can move on from that. I believe the `sem()` function is integrated in the `tbl_summary()`, when I used it as is it omit the same result as yours function :). Thank you again for your help

Comment: What do you mean by “omit the residuals”?

Comment: Actually, I just want to see if the code works or not by starting with residuals, if the function returns the residuals then I can continue adding more code to get the PSE. Your code works perfectly fine, it is just I am new and try to do it step by step to make sure things are correct before moving on :)

Comment: Hi @DaveAmstrong, I just realized the PSE equation that I put there was wrong. The correct equation for Pooled Standard Error for `k group` supposed to be `PSE = PSD*sqrt(1/n1+1nk)` [link](http://https://www.statisticshowto.com/find-pooled-sample-standard-error/) with Pooled Standard Deviation is calculated as [link](https://www.statisticshowto.com/pooled-standard-deviation/). I hope you can help me with this, I'm not so good at writing functions in R

Comment: If you use [this link](https://www.statisticshowto.com/pooled-standard-deviation/) to  define the pooled standard deviation and then [this link](https://www.statisticshowto.com/find-pooled-sample-standard-error/) to define pooled standard error, I think the function would look like the one updated at the end of the post above.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly!!